# How to compiled native_pgsql in gammu?

Tags: postgresql, gammu

I have configured gammurc and gammu --identify is working. But I received error when I do gammu-smsd -c smsdrc

Here the following error :

> gammu-smsd: the native_pgsql driver was not compiled in!

When I run gammu-smsd -v it's tell this :

```
Compiled in Features : 
OS Support :
- ALARM
- WINDOWS_SERVICE
- EVENT_LOG 
Backend services :
- NULL
- FILES
- ODBC
```

I'am using windows and pgsql
how do I fix this problem ? and
How do I compiled native_pgsql ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ODBC driver instead. It's only driver which works without additional dependencies on Windows.

To have Gammu built with native PostgreSQL driver on Windows, see our [compilation instructions](https://wammu.eu/docs/manual/project/install.html#compiling-on-microsoft-windows). Gammu will automatically search for the libraries in common locations, but you might end up needing to enter POSTGRES_INCLUDE_DIR and POSTGRES_LIBRARY manually in CMake.

Comment: This comment not works for Mac OS X, manually specify those two variables, cmake can't find it.

Comment: Which version of PostgreSQL must be used to work with Gammu 1.38.5 please?

Comment: I had more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119701/gammu-1-38-5-compile-with-native-pgsql-could-not-find-postgresql