# gammu 1.38.5 compile with native_pgsql, --Could not find PostgreSQL

Tags: c++, macos, postgresql, gammu

I m trying compile gammu 1.38.5 on my mac os x El Capitan with postgresql native lib support by fellowing instruction I found in Gammu document.

I had my PostgreSQL 9.4 installed and running my Mac OS X as database server. smsd database and user was created to support Gammu SMS gateway services. PostgreSQL was installed in default location /Library/PostgreSQL/9.4 in Mac OSX. include and lib directory can be found here.

I had set up POSTGRESQL_PATH point to /Library/PostgreSQL/9.4 and then export it to shell, I checked with FindPostgres.cmake, make sure the included file libpq-fe.h is here and then run cmake to configure it.

I tried to use cmake to with postgresql enabled by set:

```
sudo cmake -DWITH_MYSQL=OFF -DWITH_Postgres=ON -Wno-dev
```

cmake not found my postgresql default installation, shows:

```
-- Could not find PostgreSQL
```

I thought maybe have manually specify the location of include/lib in command line.

I tried to:

```
 sudo cmake -DWITH_MYSQL=OFF -DWITH_Postgres=ON -Wno-dev -DWITH_POSTGRES_INCLUDE_DIR=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/include -DWITH_POSTGRES_LIBRARY=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/lib
```

cmake still can not found my specified postgresql include/lib, shows:

```
-- Could not find PostgreSQL
```

and shows more information at the end as:

```
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

  WITH_POSTGRES_INCLUDE_DIR
  WITH_POSTGRES_LIBRARY
```

if manually variables can't be used, How I can pass the environment variables to cmake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should work:

```
cmake -DPOSTGRES_CONFIG_PREFER_PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/
```

Anyway the lookup should work better in future versions, see https://github.com/gammu/gammu/commit/d9d09574be1d0afa0609626d3bd6f604be31b8d4

Comment: I tested your advice, I found following error:

macmini16g:cmake cidylong$ cmake -DWITH_MYSQL=OFF -DWITH_Postgres=ON -Wno-dev -DPOSTGRES_CONFIG_PREFER_PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/
dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
  Expected in: /Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/lib/libJPEG.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
Trace/BPT trap: 5

Comment: I found there is a libjpeg.dylib seating in /Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/lib

Comment: @Michael. Thank you for your advice. I did it works for me now.